# masked input plugin - how to use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently i am not lucky enough to make my datepicker work inside a master page, so i switched to masked input. i found a very good website but i have no idea on how to download or implement it? here is the site: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin

[image]

When i click on the uncompressed/minified download, it directs me to a page:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js

do i need to copy these line of codes somewhere?

UPDATE:

master page:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>IslandGas</title>
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src ="/js/bootstrap.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

content page:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txtExpiry").mask("99/99/9999");
    });
</script>

    <div class ="form-group">
                <label class ="control-label col-lg-4"> Expiry Date</label> 
                <div class = "col-lg-8">  
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiry" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
```

Still not working.

Comment: See https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput#usage

Comment: @guest271314 seems its still not working inside a master page

Comment: @guest271314 my masterpage has a updatepanel. does it affect it?